# How to send facebook chat message from android application

Tags: android, facebook

Is there a way to send a facebook chat message to user's friends (not to all of them, one at each time) from android application?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I'm almost certain that there is.

Comment: Brian is probably referring to the http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/ chat API.

Comment: Yes, I'm almost certain that would do it :).

Comment: I'm familiar with the chat api facebook reference; however it is to generic and I was wondering what is the way to do that in android

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure there is a way to send chat or private messages to Facebook. I'm fairly certain those are only for the Facebook web (I might be wrong, I don't use Facebook myself, only the graph).

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ for more information on what access you get to Facebook.

Comment: There is a way, as there are many android applications for facebook chat (e.g. Go! Chat, Beejived etc)